# 64GB SSD has a 12GB Pagefile

Tags: windows, memory, windows-8.1, ssd, pagefile

I have a Microsoft Surface Pro 3 and it came with a 64GB SSD as the main harddrive (note: Surface only has this drive, like a tablet). I am trying to free up some more space on my harddrive and WinDirStat's indicated that my largest file on the SSD is a 12GB pagefile. The second biggest being at 3.1GB which is a `hiberfil.sys`. On a normal system this wouldn't be a big deal, however with limited space I am wondering why I have such a large pagefile?

What is the best solution here? I don't want to disable the pagefile as sometimes I cap the RAM, however I don't see why it would create such a large pagefile.

Comment: Wow, I suppose you know swapping to an SSD is pretty hard on it...

Comment: @BenjiWiebe Yeah I'd rather not have such a large pagefile.

Comment: I don't understand the problem.  You can either set the page file to be smaller or use an external storage device and set the page file to be there.

Comment: @BenjiWiebe That’s wrong. SSDs can take it no problem. Recent news from endurance tests clearly show what SSDs are capable of. Also, a SSD is the best location for swap.

Comment: @DanielB I somewhat agree...But swapping frequently WILL wear out the SSD faster. The question is, how long will the SSD last with/without swapping? On my computer, I'd rather just turn off swap.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- disable hibernation (This is optional — doing this step will remove `hiberfil.sys`)

  - `powercfg.exe -h off` in a command prompt will achieve this
  - this will completely disable hibernation, so you have to be able to live with that
- reduce the size of pagefile

  - to open the settings for virtual memory (pagefile) use  the Run-dialog <kbd>Windows</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd> and enter the command `sysdm.cpl` then press <kbd>Enter</kbd>
  - in advanced "System Properties" select the Tab "Advanced" and click the Button "Settings"
  - in the "Performance Options" window select the tab "Advanced" and click the "Change..." button
  - in "Virtual Memory", please uncheck  the box "Automatically manage paging file size for all drives"
  - set the radio button "User managed size", enter your desired paefile size (in MB) and hit "Define"

Comment: Why do I need to disable hibernation...?

Comment: To free up the space used by `hiberfil.sys` and with the added benefit of increasing the life of your SSD due to less read-write cycles due to hibernation. This is, of course, optional.

Comment: I recommend not disabling hibernation on any mobile device. Otherwise, you will lose your work when the battery dies.

Comment: There is ABSOLUTELY NO BENEFIT whatsoever by disabling hibernation towards increasing the life of SSD. Hibernation file gets written ONCE at the time of invoking hibernate which is way LESS than normal usage for all other sectors of the drive. SSD life expetancy is such an over-hyped and now outdated fear anyway. A user's work is way more important in case of battery loss etc. to give up hibernation, as compared to an SDD dying after good sustained use over a few years (at which time they'll be even cheaper than the price you paid originally).

Comment: @Kristian too many people are upvoting your comment and spreading an imbalanced fear, please consider changing your answer if you agree. If one is still paranoid about SSD life, then one can set the machine to go into "Sleep" instead and only hibernate when really necessary.